# Another way to manage this dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a small class that creates a new instance of a data processor object each time it needs it. I am using injection for everything but I cannot figure out how to get an activated instance of `IDataProcessingService` without injecting the `kernel`.

Is there a better way to do this. I know I can make a static gateway rather than inject but I would think that is the same issue in a different skin.

```
public class DataProcessingManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<IDataProcessingRequest, IDataProcessingService> _activeProcessingServices;

    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public DataProcessingManager(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
        _activeProcessingServices = new Dictionary<IDataProcessingRequest, IDataProcessingService>(new DataProcessingRequestComparer());
    }

    public void ProcessFor(IDataProcessingRequest dataProcessingRequest)
    {
        if (!_activeProcessingServices.ContainsKey(dataProcessingRequest))
        {
            var _processingService = _kernel.Get<IDataProcessingService>();
            _activeProcessingServices.Add(dataProcessingRequest, _processingService);

            _processingService.ProcessingFinished += 
                (sender, args) => _activeProcessingServices.Remove(dataProcessingRequest);

            _processingService.Process(dataProcessingRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 :

I had to change the accepted answer as the original suggested implementation was not creating new instances which is what I need. I know I could use the original answer by referencing the kernel but this is not what I want either. In the end the `.ToFactory()` convention in the new answer is the better way to do it.

I will contact the author of the extension and ask him to update the code sample as the `Foo..Bar` example is awkward to read.

Comment: Why don't you want to inject the kernel object?

Comment: Do you not want to inject the kernel?  Perhaps create a second interface (`IDataProcessingServiceProvider`) that the kernel (or some other class) implements?

Comment: @EricPetroelje Because it harms composability.

Comment: @deanvmc - Ahh, I get it, I was thinking `IKernel` was one of your classes, but it's part of ninject, so what you say makes perfect sense (as does D Stanley's answer)

Comment: @EricPetroelje Yeah, Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Comment: Am I missing something here?  Your StandardDataProcessingServiceProvider is just a pass through that gives the same instance of IDataProcessingService every time you call GetService().  I thought you wanted a new instance each time you called GetService().

Comment: If you want a new instance each time, you can use the [Ninject Factory Extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki) to not depend on IKernel.

Comment: Hmm, You are correct, it does give the same instance, I didn't account for that. I will have to look at your factory one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a new instance each time, you can use the [Ninject Factory Extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki) to not depend on IKernel.

Using this extension, you can create a factory interface to create instances of IDataProcessingService, but you do not need to implement that interface.  This extension can implement it for you (which under the hood will call to IKernel).

Factory interface...

```
public interface IDataProcessingServiceFactory
{
    IDataProcessingService Create();
}
```

Binding statement (which auto-generates the factory implementation at runtime)...

```
kernel.Bind<IDataProcessingServiceFactory>().ToFactory();
```

Comment: How does it know how to build the factory? In my instance I have a DataProcessingService object in the same namespace but I could have others too in different namespaces. Do you have any details on it's resolution, I read the wiki but there are too many Foo's and Bar's for me to make sense out of.

Comment: I read over the example a few times and it makes sense now. It uses the return type of the create method to provide the correct implementation via the factory. This is what I want. Marked as accepted, cheers.

Comment: If you have a good example to better explain it just edit the GH wiki from the extension project

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to "depend" on `IKernel`, you could create a second interface that would provide the service:

```
interface IDataProcessingServiceProvider
{
    IDataProcessingService GetService();
}
```

You could then have your kernel implement that interface and stub it out for testing without having to implement the whole IKernel interface.

Comment: This just moves the problem to another class that depends on IKernel.  I see little gain in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [general consensus](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) is that it is bad to let application logic depend on a container or container abstraction. However, having infrastructure components depend on the container [is fine](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorRolesVsMechanics.aspx) though.

However, try to prevent mixing application logic with infrastructure logic. The trick is often to extract classes in a way that they can be pure application or pure infrastructure.